# Smallest integers after N divisible by 2, 3, and 4

Tags: code-golf, math, number

[Give credit to whom credit is due](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29674708#29674708).

**Objective** Given an integer `N > 0`, out the smallest integers `A`, `B`, and `C` so that:

1. All of `A`, `B`, and `C` are strictly greater than `N`;
2. `2` divides `A`;
3. `3` divides `B`;
4. and `4` divides `C`.

This is a code-golf, so the shortest answer in bytes wins.

### Test cases

```
N => A, B, C
1 => 2, 3, 4
4 => 6, 6, 8
43 => 44, 45, 44
123 => 124, 126, 124
420 => 422, 423, 424
31415 => 31416, 31416, 31416
1081177 => 1081178, 1081179, 1081180
```

Comment: Can we (consistently) output the results in a different order (e.g. `C B A`) if it's clearly specified in the answer?

Comment: @MartinBüttner that is acceptable

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
~%2r4¤+‘
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=fiUycjTCpCvigJg&input=&args=MTI) or [verify all test cases](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=fiUycjTCpCvigJgKw4figqxH&input=&args=MSwgNCwgNDMsIDEyMywgNDIwLCAzMTQxNSwgMTA4MTE3Nw).

#### How it works

```
~%2r4¤+‘  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

~         Bitwise NOT; yield ~n = -(n + 1).
     ¤    Combine the three links to the left into a niladic chain:
  2         Yield 2.
   r4       Yield the range from 2 to 4, i.e., [2, 3, 4].
 %        Yield the remainder of the division of ~n by 2, 3 and 4.
          In Python/Jelly, -(n + 1) % k = k - (n + 1) % k if n, k > 0.
       ‘  Yield n + 1.
      +   Add each modulus to n + 1.
```

Comment: [7 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/79O1eThjq5DS7QfNcz4//@/oREA)

Answer (score 26):

### Python 2, 32 bytes

```python
lambda n:[n+2&-2,n/3*3+3,n+4&-4]
```

Bit arithmetic for 2 and 4, modular arithmetic for 3.

I found four 7-byte expressions for the next multiple of `k` above `n` but none shorter:

```python
n-n%k+k
~n%k-~n
n/k*k+k
~n/k*-k
```

Any gives 34 bytes when copies for `k=2,3,4`, and 33 bytes if combined:

```python
[n/2*2+2,n/3*3+3,n/4*4+4]
[n/k*k+k for k in 2,3,4]
```

But, 2 and 4 are powers of 2 that allow bit tricks to zero out the last 1 or 2 bytes.

```python
n+2&-2
n+4&-4
```

This gives 6 bytes (instead of 7) for getting the next multiple, for 32 bytes overall, beating the `for k in 2,3,4`.

Unfortunately, the promising-looking `n|1+1` and `n|3+1` have the addition done first, so incrementing the output takes parentheses.

Comment: Of the possible variants my preference is for `n+k-n%k`.

Comment: Does `n&3+1` do the addition first too?

Comment: @Tim Yup, same with all boolean operations.

Answer (score 14):

## Julia, 16 bytes

```
n->n-n%(r=2:4)+r
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=ZiA9IG4tPm4tbiUocj0yOjQpK3IKCmZvciBuID0gKDEsIDQsIDQzLCAxMjMsIDQyMCwgMzE0MTUsIDEwODExNzcpCiAgICBwcmludGxuKGYobikpCmVuZA&input=)

Answer (score 12):

## MATL, <s>15 10</s> 9 bytes

```
2:4+t5M\-
```

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Mjo0K3QyOjRcLQ&input=MTA)

Explanation:

```
2:4          #The array [2, 3, 4]
   +         #Add the input to each element, giving us [12, 13, 14]
    t        #Duplicate this array
     5M      #[2, 3, 4] again
       \     #Modulus on each element, giving us [0, 1, 2]
        -    #Subtract each element, giving us [12, 12, 12]
```

Comment: Nice answer! You can save a byte by using `5M` (automatic clipboard of function inputs) instead of the second `2:4`.

Comment: @David Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 12):

## MATL, 8 bytes

```
Qt_2:4\+
```

Uses Denis' Jelly algorithm, I'm surprised it's the same length!

[Try it online](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=UXRfMjo0XCs&input=NDIw), or, [verify all test cases](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=Mjo0K3QyOjRcLQ&input=MTA).

```
Q    % takes implicit input and increments by one
t_   % duplicate, and negate top of stack (so it's -(n+1))
2:4  % push vector [2 3 4]
\    % mod(-(n+1),[2 3 4])
+    % add result to input+1
     % implicit display
```

Comment: Well darn it. I was really proud of my 10 byte solution, but I can't beat this. Also, fun trivia: This is exactly my 300th vote. =D

Comment: Ahh but this was just taking Agawa/Dennis' algorithm, it isn't my own idea.

Comment: sometimes i keep glaring at those unicode mandarinoid elementary characters while scratching my head then i say "for sake of everything readable is that a forking runnable code" ? lol nice thing have my upvote + i ll join the matl train sooon.

Comment: @Agawa001 You should! Given know your way around Matlab pretty well, you should find it fairly straightforward, the big difference is that MATL s stack-based. There is a [MATL chat-room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39466/matl) too if you need any help!

Comment: @David that pancake based nature of matl makes it more evil scary knowignly that the raw matlab itself is a golf-friendly language regarding its high-level interactability , so imagine ....

Answer (score 6):

## Matlab, 33 bytes

Another slightly different approach

```
@(a)feval(@(x)a+1+mod(-a-1,x),2:4)
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 8 bytes

Code:

```
>D(3L>%+
```

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=PkQoM0w-JSs&input=NA).

Comment: Ah, didn't notice there was already an 05AB1E answer which is rather similar as what I had. I've deleted it, and will suggest it as a -1 golf here instead: `±D2xŸ%α` (the `2xŸ` is just an alternative for your `3L>`; and two other equal-byte alternatives could be `Ƶ…S` or `4L¦`).

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

Maps 2, 3, and 4 to the next multiple above `n`.

```
->n{(2..4).map{|e|n+e-n%e}}
```

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
m*dh/QdtS4
```

[Test suite.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=m%2adh%2FQdtS4&input=1%0A4%0A43%0A123%0A420%0A31415%0A1081177%0A&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=1%0A4%0A43%0A123%0A420%0A31415%0A1081177&debug=0)

```
       tS4  generate range [2, 3, 4]
m           for d in range...
 *dh/Qd       d*(1+input/d)
```

Thanks to [Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis) for a byte!

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, 15 bytes

```
5,2>rif{1$/)*N}
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=NSwyPnJpZnsxJC8pKk59&input=MTI) or [verify all test cases](http://cjam.tryitonline.net/#code=cU4vewogICAgNSwyPlJpZnsxJC8pKk59Ck59ZlI&input=MQo0CjQzCjEyMwo0MjAKMzE0MTUKMTA4MTE3Nw).

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>50</s> 46 bytes

```
i;f(int*a,int n){for(i=1;++i<5;*a++=n+i-n%i);}
```

*Thanks to Neil and  nwellnhof for saving 4 bytes!*

Disappointingly long. I feel like there's some bit-shifting hack in here that I don't know about, but I can't find it yet. Returns a pointer to an array holding the three elements. Full program:

```
i;f(int*a,int n){for(i=1;++i<5;*a++=n+i-n%i);}

int main()
{
    int array[3];
    int n=10;
    f(array, n);
    printf("A:%d\tB:%d\tC:%d\n",array[0],array[1],array[2]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I looked at @xnor's bit-twiddling but you need to unroll the loop for that which ends up costing you a byte overall.

Comment: Doesn't `n + i - n % i++` result in undefined behavior?

Comment: Also `s/a[i-2]/*a++/` to save two bytes.

Comment: @nwellnhof Bah, I thought of that when I unrolled his loop but it didn't occur to me that he could use it anyway.

Comment: @nwellnhof By my understanding of PPCG rules I think it's acceptable if you can find an implementation on which it works.

Comment: @Neil But the undefined behavior can be worked around without making the code larger. Here's an even shorter version using K&R function declarations: `f(a,n,i)int*a;{for(i=1;++i<5;)*a++=n+i-n%i;}`

Answer (score 4):

### Pyke, <s>11 9</s> 8 bytes

```
3FODQRc+
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=3FODQRc%2B&input=4)

```
3FODQRc+
         - Q = input()
3F       - for i in range(3): # for i in [0,1,2]
  O      -  i += 2
    Q c  -   Q-(Q%i)
       + -  i+^
```

Answer (score 4):

### Mathematica, 21 bytes

```
Ceiling[#+1,{2,3,4}]&
```

This is an unnamed function which takes a single integer as input and returns a list of the multiples.

The `Ceiling` function takes an optional second parameter which tells it to round up to the next multiple of the given number. Thankfully, it *also* automatically threads over its second argument such that we can give it a list of values and in turn we'll get rounded up multiples for all of those.

Answer (score 4):

## Octave, 20 bytes

```
@(n)n-mod(n,d=2:4)+d
```

Examples:

```
octave:60> f(123)
ans =

   124   126   124

octave:61> f(1081177)
ans =

   1081178   1081179   1081180

octave:62> f(420)
ans =

   422   423   424
```

Worth noting that we can do this up to 9 without adding any extra bytes:

```
@(n)n-mod(n,d=2:9)+d
```

Output (2520 is the smallest positive integer evenly divisible by all the single digit numbers):

```
octave:83> f(2520)
ans =

   2522   2523   2524   2525   2526   2527   2528   2529
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 27 bytes

```
f n=[div n d*d+d|d<-[2..4]]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Reng, 40 bytes

```
i1+#i2341ø>(1+)31j
i(2[¤,  q!^$]æl0eq!~
```

### 1: init

```
i1+#i2341ø
```

`i1+#i` sets the input to `1 + input`; this is because we are to work on the numbers strictly greater than the input. `234` initializes the tape with our iteration values, and `1ø` jumps to the beginning of the next line.

### 2a: loop

```
i(2[¤,  q!^$]æl0eq!~
```

`i(` puts the input at the STOS, and `2[` makes a new stack with the top 2 elements. `¤` duplicates the stack, and `,` does modulus. If there is a remainder, `q!^` breaks out of the loop to go to (b). Otherwise, we're fine to print. `$` removes the extra thingy, `]` closes the stack, and `æ` prints it nicely. `l0wq!~` terminates iff the stack contains zero members.

### 2b: that other loop

```
          >(1+)31j
        q!^
```

`(1+)` adds 1 to the STOS, and `31j` jumps to the part of the loop that doesn't take stuff from the stack. And profit.

---

That extra whitespace is really bothering me. Take a GIF.

[image: REENNNNNGGG]

Answer (score 4):

### [Labyrinth](https://github.com/mbuettner/labyrinth), 19 bytes

```
:?
:
#/)
\ #
!"*@
"
```

[Try it online!](http://labyrinth.tryitonline.net/#code=Oj8KOgojLykKXCAjCiEiKkAKIg&input=NDI)

This outputs the results in the order `C, B, A` separated by linefeeds.

#### Explanation

As usual, a short Labyrinth primer:

- Labyrinth has two stacks of arbitrary-precision integers, *main* and *aux*(iliary), which are initially filled with an (implicit) infinite amount of zeros. We'll only be using *main* for this answer.
- The source code resembles a maze, where the instruction pointer (IP) follows corridors when it can (even around corners). The code starts at the first valid character in reading order, i.e. in the top left corner in this case. When the IP comes to any form of junction (i.e. several adjacent cells in addition to the one it came from), it will pick a direction based on the top of the main stack. The basic rules are: turn left when negative, keep going ahead when zero, turn right when positive. And when one of these is not possible because there's a wall, then the IP will take the opposite direction. The IP also turns around when hitting dead ends.

Despite the two no-ops (`"`) which make the layout seem a bit wasteful, I'm quite happy with this solution, because its control flow is actually quite subtle.

The IP starts in the top left corner on the `:` going right. It will immediately hit a dead end on the `?` and turn around, so that the program actually starts with this linear piece of code:

```
:   Duplicate top of main stack. This will duplicate one of the implicit zeros
    at the bottom. While this may seem like a no-op it actually increases
    the stack depth to 1, because the duplicated zero is *explicit*.
?   Read n and push it onto main.
:   Duplicate.
:   Duplicate.
```

That means we've now got three copies of `n` on the main stack, but its depth is `4`. That's convenient because it means we can the stack depth to retrieve the current multiplier while working through the copies of the input.

The IP now enters a (clockwise) 3x3 loop. Note that `#`, which pushes the stack depth, will always push a positive value such that we know the IP will always turn east at this point.

The loop body is this:

```
#   Push the stack depth, i.e. the current multiplier k.
/   Compute n / k (rounding down).
)   Increment.
#   Push the stack depth again (this is still k).
*   Multiply. So we've now computed (n/k+1)*k, which is the number
    we're looking for. Note that this number is always positive so
    we're guaranteed that the IP turns west to continue the loop.
"   No-op.
!   Print result. If we've still got copies of n left, the top of the 
    stack is positive, so the IP turns north and does another round.
    Otherwise, see below...
\   Print a linefeed.
    Then we enter the next loop iteration.
```

After the loop was traversed (up to `!`) three times, all copies of `n` are used up and the zero underneath is revealed. Due to the `"` at the bottom (which otherwise seems pretty useless) this position is a junction. That means with a zero on top of the stack, the IP tries to go straight ahead (west), but because there's a wall it actually makes a 180 degree turn and moves back east as if it had hit a dead end.

As a result, the following bit is now executed:

```
"   No-op.
*   Multiply two zeros on top of the stack, i.e. also a no-op.
    The top of the stack is now still zero, so the IP keeps moving east.
@   Terminate the program.
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Minkolang 0.15](https://github.com/elendiastarman/Minkolang), 17 bytes

```
n$z3[zi2+$d%-+N].
```

[Try it here!](http://play.starmaninnovations.com/minkolang/?code=n%24z3%5Bzi2%2B%24d%25-%2BN%5D%2E&input=57)

#### Explanation

```
n$z                  Take number from input and store in register
   3[                Open for loop that repeats 3 times
     z               Push value in register on stack
      i2+            Loop counter plus 2
         $d          Duplicate stack
           %-+       Mod, subtract, add
              N      Output as number
               ].    Close for loop and stop.
```

Comment: + is division??

Comment: @Downgoat: Whoops. >_>

Answer (score 3):

## Matlab, 50 bytes

```
@(a)arrayfun(@(k)find(~rem(a+1:a+k,k))+a,[2 3 4])
```

Comment: At the very least, you can use `2:4` instead of `[2 3 4]`.

Answer (score 3):

## Retina, <s>62</s> <s>43</s> 26 bytes

17 bytes thanks to [@Martin Büttner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-b%C3%BCttner).

```
^
1111:
M!&`(11+):(\1*)
:
```

(Note the trailing newline.)

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XgoxMTExOgpNISZgKDExKyk6KFwxKikKOgo&input=MTExMQ)

Input in unary in `1`, output in unary in `1` separated by newlines.

### Previous 43-byte version:

```
.+
11:$&;111:$&;1111:$&
\b(1+):(\1*)1*
$1$2
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKMTE6JCY7MTExOiQmOzExMTE6JCYKXGIoMSspOihcMSopMSoKJDEkMg&input=MQ)

Input in unary, output in unary separated by semi-colon (`;`).

### Previous 62-byte version:

```
.+
$&11;$&111;$&1111
((11)+)1*;((111)+)1*;((1111)+)1*
$1;$3;$5
```

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCYxMTskJjExMTskJjExMTEKKCgxMSkrKTEqOygoMTExKSspMSo7KCgxMTExKSspMSoKJDE7JDM7JDU&input=MTExMQ)

Input in unary, output in unary separated by semi-colon (`;`).

Comment: 26 if output in the opposite order is allowed: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XgoxMTExOgpNISZgKDExKyk6KFwxKikKOgo&input=MTExMQ ... Otherwise 33 although I think there must be a shorter way that avoids the reverse sorting: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XgoxMTExOgpNISZgKDExKyk6KFwxKikKOgoKTyReYC4r&input=MTExMQ

Comment: That's enough to qualify as a separate answer?

Comment: I don't know, it's still the same idea, I just replaced generating the list manually with using overlapping matches.

Comment: Conor confirmed that the 26-byte solution is valid.

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), 26 bytes

Interestingly porting either @KevinLau's Ruby answer or @xnor's Python answer results in the same length:

```
n=>[2,3,4].map(d=>n+d-n%d)
n=>[n+2&-2,n+3-n%3,n+4&-4]
```

I have a slight preference for the port of the Ruby answer as it works up to 2<sup>53</sup>-3 while the port of the Python answer only works up to 2<sup>31</sup>-5.

Comment: `)` -> `]` as I think

Comment: @Qwertiy Whoops, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3):

## Octave, <s>27</s> <s>22</s> 20 bytes

MATLAB and Octave:

```
f=2:4;@(x)f.*ceil((x+1)./f)
```

Better (solutions are equivalent, but one may outperform the other when further golfed), MATLAB and Octave:

```
@(x)x-rem(x,2:4)+(2:4)
f=2:4;@(x)x+f-rem(x,f)
```

Only in Octave:

```
@(x)x-rem(x,h=2:4)+h
```

[Try here](https://ideone.com/gFh8IM).

Comment: My final answer is basically that one here :( http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80028/52795

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 11 bytes

-1 thanks to Adam

```apl
⎕(+-|⍨)1+⍳3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hf1EdtE4Cktm7No94VhtqPejcb//9vYmQAAA)

Explanation:

```apl
⎕(+-|⍨)1+⍳3
       1+⍳3    ⍝ 2 3 4
⎕              ⍝ read n
  +-|⍨          ⍝ {⍺ + ⍵ - ⍵ | ⍺}

Let's look at how {⍺ + ⍵ - ⍵ | ⍺} is transformed to +-|⍨:

        {⍺ + ⍵ - ⍵ | ⍺}
       {⍺} + {⍵ - ⍵ | ⍺}
         ⊣ + ({⍵} - {⍵ | ⍺})
         ⊣ + (⊢ - ({⍵} | {⍺}))
         ⊣ + (⊢ - (⊢ | ⊣))
        (⊣ + ⊢ - (⊢ | ⊣))
          (+ - (⊢ | ⊣))
          (+ - (⊣ |⍨ ⊢))
          (+ - (|⍨))
          (+-|⍨)
```

Comment: `+` and `-` and `|` are scalar functions, so `¨` isn't needed here.

Comment: [No need for `⎕←`](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO94P@jvqka2ro1j3pXaBpqP@rdbAwS/q8ABgVcJkYGAA "APL (Dyalog Unicode) – Try It Online")

Comment: i.. think that's how my solution already looks like?

Comment: Sure, but you don't need `⎕←` on TIO either, making the code length easier to understand.

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 31 bytes

```
&2v
:&\&
?!\1+:{:}%
ao\n1+:5=?;
```

Expects `N` to be present on the stack at program start. [Try it online!](http://fish.tryitonline.net/#code=JjJ2CjomXCYKPT9cMSs6ezp9JTAKYW9cbjErOjU9Pzs&input=&args=LXYgMTA4MTE3Nw)

Answer (score 2):

## R, <s>30</s> 26 bytes

(Reduced 4 bytes thanks to @Neil)

```
N=scan();cat(N+2:4-N%%2:4)
```

This (similarly to the rest of the answers I guess) adds 2:4 to the input and the reduces the remainder after running modulo on the same numbers.

Comment: As I don't know the language, is there a reason you don't use `N+2:4-N%%2:4`?

Comment: @Neil Cause I haven't thought of it I guess. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2):

## [UGL](https://github.com/schas002/Unipants-Golfing-Language), <s>51</s> <s>31</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

```
icu$l_u^^/%_u^*ocO$dddd:
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aWN1JGxfdV5eLyVfdV4qb2NPJGRkZGQ6&input=MTI)

### Previous 25-byte version:

```
iRcu$l_u$r^/%_u*ocO$dddd:
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aVJjdSRsX3Ukcl4vJV91Km9jTyRkZGRkOg&input=MTI)

### Previous 31-byte version:

```
iRcuuulu$cuuuuuu%-r^/%_u*oddcO:
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aVJjdXV1bHUkY3V1dXV1dSUtcl4vJV91Km9kZGNPOg&input=MTI)

### Previous 51-byte version:

```
i$$cuuu/%_ucuuu*@cuuuu/%_ucuuuu*@cuu/%_ucuu*ocOocOo
```

[Try it online!](http://schas002.github.io/Unipants-Golfing-Language/?code=aSQkY3V1dS8lX3VjdXV1KkBjdXV1dS8lX3VjdXV1dSpAY3V1LyVfdWN1dSpvY09vY09v&input=MTI)

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica 28 bytes

```
f@n_:=n-n~Mod~#+#&/@{2,3,4}
```

---

```
f[1]
f[4]
f[43]
f[123]
f[420]
f[31415]
f[1081177]
```

{2, 3, 4}

{6, 6, 8}

{44, 45, 44}

{124, 126, 124}

{422, 423, 424}

{31416, 31416, 31416}

{1081178, 1081179, 1081180}

---

The general case produces a general answer:

```
f[r]
```

{2 + r - Mod[r, 2], 3 + r - Mod[r, 3], 4 + r - Mod[r, 4]}

Answer (score 2):

## Java <s>70</s> 57

```
a->System.out.print(a/2*2+2+" "+(a/3*3+3)+" "+(a/4*4+4))
```

Comment: I don't know Java, but perhaps you can remove the white space around `=` in `int a = new Integer(z[0]);`

Answer (score 2):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 28 bytes

```
i2&::&::&@%-+nao&1+:&5=?;20.
```

## How it Works

```
i2&::&::&@%-+nao&1+:&5=?;20.
i2&                                  Takes N as input and stores 2 in the register
   ::                                Duplicates N twice
     &::&                            Pushes the register onto the stack and duplicates twice
          @                          Shifts top the 3 values in the stack to the right
                                     Stack now looks like: N N & N & (& = register)
            %-+nao                   Computes the smallest multiple of k > N: N+k-N%k, where k is the value of the register
               nao                   Outputs answer and a newline.
                  &1+:&5=?;          Increments register by 1, ends the program if the register equals 5
                           20.       Jumps back into the loop, skipping taking input and initializing the register
```

You could save a byte if you are allowed to take input by initializing the stack with N, but TIO doesn't allow for that. The interpreter on https://fishlanguage.com/ does.

```
2&::&::&@%-+nao&1+:&5=?;10.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/30jNygqEHFR1tfMS89UMta3UTG3trY0M9P7/LwIA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `r`, 8 bytes

```
3ɾ›ƛ⁰/⌈*
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=3%C9%BE%E2%80%BA%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%2F%E2%8C%88*&inputs=5&header=&footer=)

-1 thanks to lyxal

```
 ɾ       # Range 1...
3        # Literal
  ›      # Incremented (2...4)
   ƛ     # Map to...
       * # Product of...
          # Current item (implicit)
       * # And...
      ⌈  # Floor of
         # (Implicit) current item
     /   # Divided by...
    ⁰    # Input
```

Comment: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=3%C9%BE%E2%80%BA%C6%9B%E2%81%B0%2F%E2%8C%88*&inputs=5&header=&footer=) for 8 bytes

Comment: @lyxal Nice! I forgot implicit input worked like that.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 18 bytes

```
2 3 4&([*>:@<.@%~)
```

[Try it online!](https://a296a8f7c5110b2ece73921ddc2abbaaa3c90d10.googledrive.com/host/0B3cbLoy-_9Dbb0NaSk9MRGE5UEU/index.html#code=2%203%204%26%28%5B*%3E%3A%40%3C.%40%25%7E%29%20123)

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript, 22 bytes

```
~..2/)2*@3/)3*@4/)4*]`
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=fi4uMi8pMipAMy8pMypANC8pNCpdYA&input=NDIw)

Alternative 22-byte solution:

```
~..[4 2 3]{.@@/)*@}/]`
```

[Try it online!](http://golfscript.tryitonline.net/#code=fi4uWzQgMiAzXXsuQEAvKSpAfS9dYA&input=NDIw)

Answer (score 1):

### Actually, 22 bytes

```
╗52x"╝1`;╛@%Y@╜<*`╓"£M
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=4pWXNTJ4IuKVnTFgO-KVm0AlWUDilZw8KmDilZMiwqNN&input=NA)

Fun fact: 3 bugs in Actually's interpreter were found and fixed while writing this program.

Not so fun fact: Those 3 bugs prevented this solution from being much shorter.

Explanation:

```
╗52x"╝1`;╛@%Y@╜<*`╓"£M
╗                       push input to reg0
 52x                    push range(2,5) ([2,3,4])
    "╝1`;╛@%Y@╜<*`╓"£M  map (for n in [2,3,4]):
     ╝                    push n to reg1
      1`;╛@%Y@╜<*`╓       find the smallest integer k where:
        ;╛@%Y               k is divisible by n and...
             @╜<*           is greater than the input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathcad, [tbd] bytes

[image]

function version allows for simple evaluation of different divisor sets.

---

*Mathcad byte equivalence scheme not yet determined.   Keyboard equivalence ~ 16 bytes.*

Answer (score 1):

## Desmos, <s>141</s> 136 bytes

```
a=1
b=2\operatorname{ceil}\left(.5a+.1\right)
c=3\operatorname{ceil}\left(\frac{a}{3}+0.1\right)
d=4\operatorname{ceil}\left(.25a+.1\right)
```

[Demonstration](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rlq0i2qsuj)
Fixed the outputs while shaving off a few bytes.

Comment: Also, it's possible to remove the `a=1\n`. Having the user click on the `a` to set it is equivalent input.

Comment: But doing that would create an error.

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 12 bytes

```
Ṫ;234z%ᵛ0&>ᵛ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRuX/eobcOjpqaHuzprH26d8P/hzlXWRsYmVaoPt842ULMDkv//RxvqmOiYGOsYGhnrmBgZ6Bgbmhia6hgaWBgampvHAgA)

Takes input through the output variable and gives output through the input variable. (Shortest I could get it without reversed I/O was `~{>ᵛ}Ṫ;234z%ᵛ0∧Ṫ`, which at 16 bytes ties an extremely awkward implementation of Dennis' algorithm: `+₁Xṅg;234z%ᵐ+ᵐ↙X`.)

```
           ᵛ    Every element of
         &      the input variable
          >     is strictly greater than
                the output variable.
                Also, the input variable
Ṫ               is a list of three elements
     z          which zipped
 ;234           with 2, 3, and 4
       ᵛ0       produces 0 for each pair
      %         when the first element is taken mod the second.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 8 bytes

```
3õ@Ä c°X
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=M/VAxCBjsFg&input=NDIw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 40 bytes

```forth
: f 5 2 do dup i over i mod - + . loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCgIxEATv@4pir5Kwk80SccHPGKOCMiGo348TD10NTXXR9r67WxnV@4nCRiAr@VN5oN9rs3ppxnHA81St7CbWv5HwDT@DOzPb@dLYmYQ6xZHVIGEwhsW4SpRtbMtRJCVq/wE)

#### Explanation

Uses modulo of 2, 3, and 4 to get the distance to the next divisible number and then adds it to the original number (+1)

#### Code Explanation

```forth
: f                \ start a new word definition
  5 2              \ set up parameters loop from 2 to 4
  do               \ start a counted loop
    dup i over     \ duplicate N, get the loop index, and then copy N again
    i mod          \ get N mod Loop-index (distance from last divisible number)
    -              \ subtract from Loop-index to get distance to next divisible number
    +              \ add distance-to-next to N to get number
    .              \ print 
  loop             \ end counted loop
;                  \ end word definition
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>141</s> 129 bytes

```java
interface C{static void main(String[]a){var n=Double.valueOf(a[0])+1;for(int i=1;++i<5;)System.out.print(i*Math.ceil(n/i)+" ");}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcwxCsIwFADQq4ROicFoB0GIHQRXcehYOnzTRH9tE0l/A1J69th3gNdDgn3ffXJGTzY6MJZdl4mA0LAUsGMjoOc1RfSvpgWxJIjMV7cwPwerEgyzfTgOzbEVstQuRL5FDKtSS4mXkxb1byI7qjCT@m4Jcdzdgd7KWBy4P6CQBSuEXtec8/kP)

You may notice that no `class` has been defined, but instead an interface. This is just to further golf the code. Since the interface hasn't been given a `public` access modifier, the `main` method doesn't need it, either.

For a better understanding of this code, it's shown below with the variable `a` remnamed to its traditional name `args`:

```java
var n = Double.valueOf(args[0]) + 1;
for (int i = 1; ++i < 5;)
    System.out.print(i * Math.ceil(n / i) + " ");
}
```

The program inputs a value as a command-line argument which is immediately incremented for compactness before being stored in the `double` variable `n`. Next, the for loop cycles through each integer `i` from 2 through to 4, printing the output values each cycle. [See here](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lxkzawlpwa) for an interactive demonstration of the formula used to calculate said values.

In order to further golf this code, I think finding a way to use Java 6 would be ideal due to the `static` block's functionality, as expressed below:

```java
public class Foo {
    static {
        // Your code here
    }
}
```

As you can see, although it's definitely good practice, explicitly defining the `main` method isn't necessary in this particular version of Java. (Correct me if that was incorrectly phrased)

Unfortunately, in performing such a conversion, the `var` keyword would no longer exist (since it was introduced in Java 10). More importantly, reconstructing the value input mechanism would be necessary, since a `static` block obviously doesn't have any method parameters, and especially not for command-line arguments. Feel free to leave comments and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 41 bytes

```c
i=5;f(int*n){for(;--i;n[i-2]=*n+i-*n%i);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDBasMwDL3nK0RLwUnsEScpKbjpV@SW5TASexNsakndU8i3Z4pZWwYV4gnJ0nuSe/XZ98sWqf@@DRaOVz/g@e3rtGC9N04g@YTiyZ1HYZRCQy2qvKsTSlEltMPYzMt2sA7JQgNVFPEA/HwgiRimCNgCrFVqi848Mm@vvm06qGHSEkr2QoLOGco8k1DoUu@5kB20rqrZPKnWVQIBj2aGwxEaDml6F3x0rpYQtwUt/yf@79kJil@ULyMrOLHZDVCfgDH4O23knUvyOVlAHTDvXvGsfxiS@bn/aP1tJF49mpdf)

Answer (score 1):

## MMIX, 36 bytes (9 instrs)

Uses bit tricks to avoid dividing by 2 or 4 (sadly, it's unavoidable for 3)

```
foo ADDU $2,$0,1        // a = n + 1
    ANDN $2,$2,1        // a &= ~1
    ADDU $1,$0,3        // c = n + 3
    PUT  rD,0
    DIVU $0,$0,3
    GET  $0,rR          // b = n % 3
    SUBU $0,$1,$0       // b = c - b (= n + 3 - n % 3)
    ANDN $1,$1,3        // c &= ~3
    POP  3,0            // return a,b,c
```

Answer (score 0):

## Scala, 268 bytes

```
def logic(y:Int)(x: Int) = (x)%y ==0

def fun(n:Int,  logic: Int => Boolean) : Int = { 
  if (logic(n)) n else fun(n+1, logic) 
} 
for { 
    N <- Array[Int](1,4, 43, 123, 420, 31415, 1081177)
    ABC <- Array[Int](2,3,4)
    res = fun(x+1, logic(i) _)
    } yield res
```

Comment: Scala version...

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Please include your language's name on the header. [This](/q/80189#comment196935_80189) made me realize it is Scala. Please include your bytecount along with the header, since this is [tag:code-golf].

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-n`, 26 bytes

```perl
//;map{say$'+$_-$'%$_}2..4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/19f3zo3saC6OLFSRV1bJV5XRV1VJb7WSE/P5P9/QyPjf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7r5gEA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{[$^a+$_-$a%$_ for 2..4]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYzbCoMwDIav7VP0ohsTOzUxasdwL7KDCFMY6Db0SsRn75rixSCHL3@S/9uOfWGHed9VdrmqRxOp@qianapl9xklxjHdV8t46F/vdgrlIoIhuT2j5CyCqZlld1BJKFYLsrpI1DLTkgTxUGgOIyjjicgtcpckAL0C6CTAgot7wdSfofMgZBcnZkCQs8zgDv@bgNQAlKW38mj0BqcNTPoD)

Answer (score 0):

### Arm Thumb (no div), 30 bytes

Raw machine code:

```
3001 1c42 2301 439a 600a 2302 3202 439a
608a 1c03 3b03 dcfd 1ac0 6048 4770
```

Uncommented assembly:

```armasm
        .text
        .thumb
        .globl smallest_after_n
        .thumb_func
smallest_after_n:
        adds    r0, #1
        adds    r2, r0, #1
        movs    r3, #1
        bics    r2, r3
        str     r2, [r1]
        movs    r3, #2
        adds    r2, #2
        bics    r2, r3
        str     r2, [r1, #8]
        movs    r3, r0
.Lmod_loop:
        subs    r3, #3
        bgt     .Lmod_loop
.Lmod_loop_end:
        subs    r0, r3
        str     r0, [r1,#4]
        bx      lr
```

#### Explanation

Happens to be valid Thumb-1, but feel free to use Thumb-2 to compete.

It is easier to understand in the equivalent C code.

```c
void smallest_after_n(int32_t N, int32_t out[3])
{
    ++N; // increment N
    // Even multiple of 2: Lowest bit is zero.
    int32_t A = (N + 1) & ~1;
    out[0] = A;
    // Even multiple of 4: Lowest 2 bits are zero.
    // Since we know the lowest bit of A is zero, we reuse it. 
    int32_t C = (A + 2) & ~2;
    out[2] = C;
    // Calculate the "inverse modulo" using a subtraction loop.
    // N % 3 == 0 => 0
    // N % 3 == 1 => -2
    // N % 3 == 2 => -1
    int32_t inv_modulo = N;
    while ((inv_modulo -= 3) > 0) {}
    // Round up by subtracting a negative
    int32_t B = N - inv_modulo;
    out[1] = B;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 25 bytes

```arturo
$[n][map 2..4'd->d+n-n%d]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?uMM6H6)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 11 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 9.05 bytes

```
DA~234d%+1+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuharXRzrjIxNUlS1DbUhIlCJBYsNjYwhTAA)

Port of Dennis's Jelly answer.

##### Explanation

```python
DA~234d%+1+  # Implicit input
DA~          # Duplicate and bitwise not
   234d      # Push [2, 3, 4] (digits of 234)
       %     # Push ^^ modulo ^
        +1+  # Add and increment
```